# ng-file-upload and meanjs not working together

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use the ng-file-upload within the meanjs stack, but I can't figure out how to make it work properly.

I followed all the steps illustrated in https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and I've tried all the examples, but nothing worked.

I've also tried the S3 upload and I've obtained the same result.

Has someone already tested this module within meanjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah it works fine. You can see the complete answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200864/uploading-video-file-without-using-input-type-file).

you can see the html,client controller and server controller part regarding your question
this is for video but you can change the input type for uploading the images and audio files.

Include ng-file-upload js file and ng-file-upload-shim js file and other server side dependencies properlty .

Comment: I don't receive an error message, but the upload method called from the UI doesn't produce any action.

Comment: i will share the code by mid night with complete details as i am little busy right now

Comment: It would be great! Thanks!